# Create a string with node of BST that has the same value

Tags: c, string, binary-search-tree

I've a struct like (BST):

```
typedef struct node {
  char* name;  
  int age;
  struct node* left;       
  struct node* right;      
} node_t;
```

and i've to make a function like: `char* getSameAge(node_t* s, int age)` that returns a string like name1:name2:....nameN with node that has == age

I made this solution, it works with tests but using valgrind it gives me errors...does anyone give me an advice or an alternative/better solution?!

```
void visitTree(node_t* s,char buf[N],int age) {
  if(s!=NULL) {
    visitTree(s->left,buf,age);
    if(s->age == age) {
      if(strlen(buf) == 0) strcpy(buf,s->name);
      else{
       strcat(buf,s->name);
       if(s->left != NULL || s->right != NULL) strcat(buf,":");
      }
    }
    visitTree(s->right,buf,age);
  }
}

char* getSameAge(node_t* s, int age) {

  char buf[N];
  visitTree(r,buf,age);
  if(strlen(buf) == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  else {
    char *aux = malloc(strlen(buf));
    strcpy(aux,buf);
    return aux;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** The following line has an error (may be others but this is definitely one of them):

```
char *aux = malloc(strlen(buf));
```

**Recall:** `strlen` returns the string length, you are missing a NULL terminator for `aux` (since `strcpy` will copy everything *including* the NULL terminator).

It should be as follows:

```
char *aux = malloc( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( buf ) + 1 ) );
```

**2.** Change the following line:

```
char buf[N];
```

... to be the following:

```
char buf[N] = { 0 };
```

... by not initializing every element in the array to 0 (or NULL terminators - '\0'), `buf` will take on arbitrary values from a previous stack frame.

**Aside:** I believe that all you would *really* have to do to solve error *2* is ensure that the first element of `buf` is 0. This *only* works because you are only using `strcpy` and `strcat` which copies the NULL terminator from the source string to the destination string.

Comment: yes thank you, but now i've only 1 error:
==2879== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==2879== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
maybe 'strcat' problems..

Comment: @user2590319, No problem. Please accept the solution that best solved your problem so that others who encounter the same problem can find the solution that helped you.